# how to get location in android debugging mode?

Tags: android, location

I am trying to get gps and network location in android. But every time I get location null.
`LocationManager` getting null in debugging mode.

Here is my Code

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

private static Timer timer = new Timer();
public Location mLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    _startService();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void _startService() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            _serviceWork();

        }
    }, 1000, 30000);
}

private void _serviceWork() {
    new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    _shutdownService();
}

private void _shutdownService() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
}
```